# Opacity of a TWinControl?

Tags: delphi, graphics, vcl, opacity, alphablending

How could one change the opacity of a TWinControl based control? And why didn't they add this capability to TControl/TWinControl level (why only TForm)?

Comment: I don't how you'd do it. As I understand it, Windows only added the translucency to windows, which is why TForm can handle it, but not individual controls. Remember that most of the VCL is simply a wrapper around the Windows Common Controls, and so if Windows doesn't do it, the related VCL control rarely will either. Third-party components often then extend the basic functionality.

Comment: @_J_: You are correct. Why not add this as an answer so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controlling the opacity of a window is offered by a feature called *layered windows*. You can [read more about the feature on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx). The feature is only available for *top-level* windows. As far as I can tell, [Desktop Window Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969540.aspx) (Vista's "glass" effect) is also only available for top-level windows.

Alternatives available for child windows are to use [window regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102.aspx) to mark certain areas of a window as completely transparent, or to use [bitmap alpha blending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351.aspx) to draw the whole control yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort for linking.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Lars.

I don't how you'd do it. As I understand it, Windows only added the translucency to windows, which is why TForm can handle it, but not individual controls. Remember that most of the VCL is simply a wrapper around the Windows Common Controls, and so if Windows doesn't do it, the related VCL control rarely will either. Third-party components often then extend the basic functionality.

Comment: Please edit this, even controls are windows (`HWND` type). The important point is that support isn there only for windows without the `WS_CHILD` style. A form with an overridden `CreateParams` method which sets the `WS_CHILD` style can't be translucent either.